# Most efficient way to queue up AJAX requests, given that I need input from previous ones?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I'm building an application in SharePoint that needs to make three separate AJAX requests:

- A call to the Search API for all people with a specific job title for the account ID (searchUsers).
- A call to the User Profile API, using *each* account name retrieved in searchUsers (getUserProps).
- A second call to the User Profile API for each user's manager's name, using the manager's account name retrieved in getUserProps (a second getUserProps).

The three operations I parenthesized above are part of a custom library I'm writing to take some of the heavy lifting out of writing the ajax objects over and over again.  Not sure how much of the library you all need to see, and I didn't want to crap up this question with a bunch of code, so I added the operative parts of the library in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p29b4ebt/).

So, this is mostly me having a poor understanding of deferred promises and the ins and outs of ajax (and probably the whole language, in general).  But I want to do the above without having a bunch of nested functions, if that's possible.  Or to know what the best practice/most efficient way to accomplish this.

**Update**
Based on Vadim Gremyachev's suggestions, I went the `jQuery.when` approach:

```
searchPeople().then(function(result){

    //prepare promises 
    var promises = result.items.map(function(q){
        return getUserProps(q.Manager);
    });

    //resolve for each of the promises
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
        console.log('Promises resolved.')
    });

})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
});

function searchPeople(){
    var api = new ApiHelper('https://sharepoint/sites/subsite');

    var options = {
        query:'Job Title',
        props:['Manager']
    };        
    return api.searchUsers(options);
}

function getUserProps(account){
    var api = new ApiHelper('https://sharepoint/sites/subsite');
    var encName = encodeURIComponent(account);
    return api.getUserProperties(encName);
}
```

You'll notice, in the `$.when.apply`line, that I've just got a console shout.  This is because I can't get the promises to resolve.  I can see, in developer tools, all of my getUserProperties calls running.  But they never resolve, that "Promises resolved" call never occurs.

Help?

Comment: You should always use `then` instead of `done`, to allow for chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option would be to return promise per every search result row:

```
api.searchUsers(options).done(function(data){
   var admins = data.items;
   var promises = admins.map(function(item){
       var accountName = admins[i].AccountName;
       return getUserProperties(accountName);
   });


});
```

and then resolve all the promises using [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var profileProperties = arguments[i][0];  
        console.log(profileProperties.DisplayName);
      }
   });
```

**Example**

```
function searchPeople()
{
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'";
    return $.getJSON(requestUrl);
}



function getUserProperties(account){
    var encName = encodeURIComponent(account);
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encName + "'";
    return $.getJSON(requestUrl);
}


searchPeople()
.then(function(result){

   //prepare promises 
   var promises = result.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.map(function(r){
       var accountName = r.Cells[3].Value;
       return getUserProperties(accountName);
   });

   //resolve for each of the promises
   $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var profileProperties = arguments[i][0];  
        console.log(profileProperties.DisplayName);
      }
   });

})
.fail(function(error){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic and exactly what I was looking for.  As soon as I figure out how to load one more ajax request into the process, I'll edit my question with the final product.

Thank you!

Comment: ... and I couldn't get it to work.  Updated my code above.